# using ant read the build.xml ,according to the order written in <include >tag

Tags: ant, build.xml

Here i want to compile/run first ExceuteLeadTest.class and then ExceuteContactTest.class by the ant ..But while exceuting it first it comipling/running ExcecuteContactTest.java/ExceuteContactTest.class

```html
<project>
<target name="run" depends="compile">
<include name="testScript/ExceuteLeadTest.class" />
<include name="testScript/ExceuteContactTest.class" />
</target>
<project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ant you can use the [sequential](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sequential.html) tag to run tasks in order.  Normally Ant processes dependencies and runs each only once if they are included repeatedly in depends.

Example

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <sequential>
        <antcall target="run1"/>
        <antcall target="run2"/>
    </sequential>
</target>

<target name="run1" depends="compile">
    <!-- however you run the 1st class -->
</target>

<target name="run2" depends="compile">
    <!-- however you run the 2nd class -->
</target>
```

Comment: can u please explain in detail as i am new to ANT..where to write the above tags in build.xml?

Comment: I added an example of one target calling two other targets.