# Junit -Run test cases/classes as per order in build.xml by ant

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have 2 classes /testcases in build.xml.The names are not in alphabetical order but in logical manner .When executing,test cases are executing in alphabetical order.

How can I execute test cases or clasess in junit as in same order from written in build .xml.

Kindly help me out

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202602/using-ant-read-the-build-xml-according-to-the-order-written-in-include-tag?

Comment: No solutions given in the above link also